# Use WordPress file upload in my plugin - on frontend and on backend?

Tags: customization, plugin-development

Is there a way to use wp multifile upload system in my plugin?

Comment: If you need this for frontend (as you commented to some answers) you should write that in your question description. Many users might think about backend first.

Comment: I change title of my question,sorry

Comment: This is what I thought. Sorry for that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always include the stuff related to swfupload, yes. But there will be a better way in WP 3.1: you'll be able to use the whole upload UI.

Comment: Are you sure ? :) I need to enable wp multifile system on frontend,to enable users just to upload an images,video,...,on frontend.Just to upload it with wp multifile upload system

Comment: Sorry,what do you mean with this : "You could always include the stuff related to swfupload" ?

Comment: The js for multi-file uploads is swfupload... you merely need to enqueue it: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: And yes, I'm quite sure that there was a recent commit related to allowing plugins to use the whole uploads UI (and possibly for other things than uploading media). Whether you'll be able to bypass permission checks is another question entirely...

Comment: can you elaborate? how will this be done? (which commit are you referring to?)

Comment: I will try to implement this http://demo.swfupload.org/v220/index.htm

Comment: It would help if you scanned the WP trac for the commit in question. It occurred in the past 2 or 3 weeks...

Answer (score 0):

There is an action to call the media buttons.
Forgive me I don't know it at the moment, but you could look it up by yourself.

Comment: ok,thank you,I know for that,but I would like to enable this feature on frontend,to enable my users uploads an image,video,...,but with wordpress multfile uplaod system,just to upload it.Is this thing possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'd let them upload through Picasa or Google Docs and embed that page.  What say ye, fellow WP Developers?  If not, I'd also really like to know an answer.

Comment: I would just like to use wp multiple file upload on frontend and backend :) in my plugin,because I want to upload on my server

Answer (score 0):

This may be abit late but I found a helpful tutorial on [Using WordPress’ Built-in Media Upload](http://lewayotte.com/2010/09/27/using-wordpress-built-in-media-upload/)